# JMeter - Unable to send mail with "Subject", Body Messages & attachment using SMTP client

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Using groovy "SMTPClinet" code which is sending mail to Outlook server. However email attachments, messages and subject are missing.

We are unable to get the right instances/function for attachments, messages and subject. we are using "SMTPClient".

Here is the actual code.

import org.apache.commons.net.smtp.SMTPClient;

```
SMTPClient client = new SMTPClient();
//client.setPassiveLocalIPAddress("${IP}");
client.connect(xx.xx.xx.xx");
client.login();
client.setSender("emp1@estmail.net");
client.addRecipient("emp1@estmail.net");
mess = "this is test mail";
boolean success = client.sendShortMessageData(mess);
log.info("Success: " + success);
if (!success) {
  SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
  SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Failed to connect client");
}
client.logout()
client.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, never refer variables as ${VAR} in your Groovy script, it ruins all the benefits of the [Compilable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/Compilable.html) interface and dramatically slows down your script.  Use `vars.get("IP")` instead
2. It is recommended to avoid scripting where possible and go for scripting only where there are no alternatives. In your case JMeter provides [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) which could be used for all your test scenarios. See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) guide for comprehensive information on the domain
3. If you still need scripting for any reason consider the following:

   - Use [SmtpSampler.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/protocol/mail/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/smtp/sampler/SmtpSampler.java) source code for reference
   - If anything goes wrong - the best place to look into for troubleshooting is *jmeter.log* file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll modify the variable declaration in the script.  I'm forced to use script, since smtp sampler does not support IP spoofing.